# Error when trying to call a custom popup window from another class with startActivity

Tags: android

I'm new to android developing and I'm trying to open a popup window from my main class, which is created on another class.
The problem is that I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to call the popup via a button click on main class:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

If I move the code for popup to the button' s case, I can open by click on it, but I cannot use any of methods are on the other class(at least I don't know how).
I've search a lot and found some similar threads, but everything I tried failed, and the error didn't change.

So, I prefer to have all code for popup in the second class and just call it from main class, but doesn't bother me if I can have access to the methods of the second class.

Here is the code of popup window:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService     (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));
    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 590, 400, true);
    pw.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 50);
```

And the main class button's code:

```
case R.id.bkeyb:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, keyboard.class));

     break;
```

I desided to include all code for popup to the main activity and delete the second class.
So I made a method popup, which include the above code for popup window under the onCreate of main class. I tested it with the button which I want to open the popup and worked.
Then I made an Initialise method for all buttons of popup window, in which use findViewById for the resources and onClickListeners definition.

The code now for popup became:

```
public void Popup(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));
    initialize();
    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 590, 400, true);
    pw.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 50);

}
```

And the onClickListener code for button which launch popup window:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bkeyb:
        Popup();

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.balpha:
            tvcheck.setText("Α");
           Log.e(null, "you pressed a");
        break;
        case R.id.bbeta:
            tvcheck.setText("Β");
        break;  
        }

     break;
```

I just added 2 buttons for testing.

Now when press the button I get a crash with a **NullPointerException.**
So again something is wrong.

Comment: is this the activity code or a fragment?

Comment: The first is the onCreate for the popup window. After that is a method for initializing views and a method for onClickListener for the buttons. The second is just the case of onClick view for the button which calls the popup. It's not all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Framework defined three kinds of window types.Application window,Sub window,System window. Popup window belongs to Sub window and Sub Window must have a parent window.So you cannot set the popup window to be a activity's main window.poor english,hope you can understand what i mean!

Comment: I think I can thanks. So, I must have the code on my main activity. This popup acts like a simple keyboard, and I don't want to have all onklick listeners for about 25 buttons in main activity. I have the onCreate and onClick methods in a separate keyboard class. Is possible to bind these methods on popup by clicking the button which launch it, or I have to put them on the main class too?

Comment: Ok, I moved a litle farther. I've found(with help of this forum) that needed to change the way I call findViewById, by adding getContentView. Now popup loads without error, but still the buttons don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I was trying to use the main onClickListener view(this which I have for main class's buttons) and add popup's buttons in a switch inside a switch's case. This doesn't work.
I needed to include the onClickListener view method for every button in the main Popup method I made. Maybe there is a more clear and compact way, but only this worked so far for me.

The working code is this:

```
public void Popup(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));
    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 590, 400, true);
    pw.update();
    pw.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 50);
    balpha = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.balpha);
    balpha.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tvcheck.append("Α");
        }
    });
    bbeta = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.bbeta);
    bbeta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tvcheck.append("Β");
        }
    });
```

.......... and the same for another 20 buttons.

And on main onClick view just the call of Popup() method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bkeyb:
        Popup();
        tvcheck.setText("");        

     break;
```

.....and some more button cases here.